# Avoid multi forEach loop in JSTL in JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp, for-loop, jstl

I want to avoid multi loop in JSTL which is shown by the code presented below. I got attributes `WRTSC`, `DTA`, `DTA_PRZEDST_TR_OSW` from api response and they are passing randomly so that is why the code looks like this.

```
<c:forEach items="${ctx.model.customerAttributes}" var="customerAttribute">
<tr>
    <td class="code">${customerAttribute.subGroupName}</td>
    <td class="value">
        <c:forEach items="${customerAttribute.attributes}" var="attribute">
            ${attribute.attrName == 'WRTSC' ? attribute.attrValue : ''}
        </c:forEach>
    </td>
    <td class="value">
        <c:forEach items="${customerAttribute.attributes}" var="attribute">
            ${attribute.attrName == 'DTA' ? attribute.attrValue : ''}
        </c:forEach>
    </td>
    <td class="value">
        <c:forEach items="${customerAttribute.attributes}" var="attribute">
            ${attribute.attrName == 'DTA_PRZEDST_TR_OSW' ? attribute.attrValue : ''}
        </c:forEach>
    </td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

I need to read every attribute (if there is not attribute sent I need to create empty `<td></td>` block.

Can it be done in one loop instead of three (in this case this number respresents the number of different attributes).

Thanks for helping.

Comment: customerAttribute.attributes[0] .. [1]...[2] should have the values respectively, you can directly access them.

Comment: But, as I said, [0] can contains `WRTSC`, `DTA` or `DTA_PRZEDST_TR_OSW` as well...

Comment: you need to process that on server side, place them in order from the server side.

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo I have no influence on it. But can you check my answer - is this better solution?

Comment: yes, that's better. Previously you outer loop had atleast 9 inner iterations now you reduced that repetition to one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got something like this now. Guys, do you think this is better?

```
<c:forEach items="${ctx.model.customerAttributes}" var="customerAttribute">
<tr>
    <c:set var="WRTSC" value="" />
    <c:set var="DTA" value="" />
    <c:set var="DTA_PRZEDST_TR_OSW" value="" />

    <c:forEach items="${customerAttribute.attributes}" var="attribute">
        <c:if test="${WRTSC eq ''}">
            <c:set var="WRTSC" value="${attribute.attrName == 'WRTSC' ? attribute.attrValue : ''}" />
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${DTA eq ''}">
            <c:set var="DTA" value="${attribute.attrName == 'DTA' ? attribute.attrValue : ''}" />
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${DTA_PRZEDST_TR_OSW eq ''}">
            <c:set var="DTA_PRZEDST_TR_OSW" value="${attribute.attrName == 'DTA_PRZEDST_TR_OSW' ? attribute.attrValue : ''}" />
        </c:if>
    </c:forEach>

    <td class="code">${customerAttribute.subGroupName}</td>
    <td class="value">${WRTSC}</td>
    <td class="value">${DTA}</td>
    <td class="value">${DTA_PRZEDST_TR_OSW}</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
<c:forEach items="${ctx.model.customerAttributes}" var="customerAttribute">
    <tr>
        <td class="code">${customerAttribute.subGroupName}</td>
        <td class="value">
            <c:forEach items="${customerAttribute.attributes}" var="attribute">
             ${(attribute.attrName == 'WRTSC') || (attribute.attrName == 'DTA') || (attribute.attrName == 'DTA_PRZEDST_TR_OSW')? attribute.attrValue : ''}
            </c:forEach>
        </td>

    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

or

```
<c:forEach items="${ctx.model.customerAttributes}" var="customerAttribute">
    <tr>
        <td class="code">${customerAttribute.subGroupName}</td>
        <td class="value">
            <c:forEach items="${customerAttribute.attributes}" var="attribute">
                <c:if test="${(attribute.attrName == 'WRTSC') || (attribute.attrName == 'DTA') || (attribute.attrName == 'DTA_PRZEDST_TR_OSW')}">
                 ${attribute.attrValue}
                </c:if>
            </c:forEach>
        </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: That's not my point. I need to **show** this in this order: `WRTSC`, `DTA` and `DTA_PRZEDST_TR_OSW`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than running 3 inner loop take 3 inner variable for

```
var WRTSC='';
var DTA ='';
var DTA_PRZEDST_TR_OSW ='';
```

and run only one inner loop in which check the condition with the variables , if condition is match set the value of variable otherwise by default value is '' .